# Encoding and Decoding in Node js

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, .net

I have a string, On which I need to encode it into "iso-8859-1" and then I need to convert back it into a readable string.

Is there any way to do this in node js natively? If I am encoding it into "iso-8859-1" then do I need to use the same to decode it back?

I am able to do it in .Net

```
string encodedData = "VABpAG0AZQAgAHMAZQByAGUAaQBzAA==";
Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"); // encoding in "iso-8859-1"
byte[] = decodedbuff = convert.FromBase64String(encodedData);   // getting buffer
result = encoding.GetString(decodedbuff);    //decoding
```

How to achieve it in node js?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a buffer from your encoded base64 string and then use `toString()` with `latin1` (iso-8859-1 is latin1 in nodejs)  on the buffer to get the decoded string:

```
const encoded = "VABpAG0AZQAgAHMAZQByAGUAaQBzAA==";
const buffer = Buffer.from(encoded, 'base64');
console.log(buffer.toString('latin1')); // prints T i m e   s e r e i s
```

Comment: I have tried this way and i am getting spaces between each character like "T i m e s e r e i s". If I change "latin1" to "utf16le"(Each character has 2 bytes) then it is working fine. but when I have encoded it in "iso-8859-1"  then at the time of decoding why it is not giving the correct result?

Comment: Seems like the value that was converted to `VABpAG0AZQAgAHMAZQByAGUAaQBzAA==` was encoded with something else than latin1 -> if I convert "Time sereis" to base64 in node I get `VGltZSBzZXJlaXM=`.